# Laravel One to Many Relation. Save Data

Tags: laravel, controller, relationship

How can I make the relationship created in the database?

1.This is my sale controller store function.
2.I want to save edit_warranty field in **product_sales** table.
3.but I don't know. Is there something missing or not?
4. am trying to save date. but I am Not getting anything.
5.please help to find the method.

You can see my code below.

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request->all();
        if(isset($request->reference_no)) {
            $this->validate($request, [
                'reference_no' => [
                    'max:191', 'required', 'unique:sales'
                ],
            ]);
        }

        $data['user_id'] = Auth::id();
        $cash_register_data = CashRegister::where([
            ['user_id', $data['user_id']],
            ['warehouse_id', $data['warehouse_id']],
            ['status', true]
        ])->first();

        if($cash_register_data)
            $data['cash_register_id'] = $cash_register_data->id;

        if(isset($data['created_at']))
            $data['created_at'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($data['created_at']));
        else
            $data['created_at'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        //return dd($data);
        if($data['pos']) {
            if(!isset($data['reference_no']))
                $data['reference_no'] = 'posr-' . date("Ymd") . '-'. date("his");


            $balance = $data['grand_total'] - $data['paid_amount'];
            if($balance > 0 || $balance < 0)
                $data['payment_status'] = 2;
            else
                $data['payment_status'] = 4;

            if($data['draft']) {
                $lims_sale_data = Sale::find($data['sale_id']);
                $lims_product_sale_data = Product_Sale::where('sale_id', $data['sale_id'])->get();
                foreach ($lims_product_sale_data as $product_sale_data) {
                    $product_sale_data->delete();
                }
                $lims_sale_data->delete();
            }
        }
        else {
            if(!isset($data['reference_no']))
                $data['reference_no'] = 'sr-' . date("Ymd") . '-'. date("his");
        }

        $document = $request->document;
        if ($document) {
            $v = Validator::make(
                [
                    'extension' => strtolower($request->document->getClientOriginalExtension()),
                ],
                [
                    'extension' => 'in:jpg,jpeg,png,gif,pdf,csv,docx,xlsx,txt',
                ]
            );
            if ($v->fails())
                return redirect()->back()->withErrors($v->errors());

            $documentName = $document->getClientOriginalName();
            $document->move('public/sale/documents', $documentName);
            $data['document'] = $documentName;
        }
        if($data['coupon_active']) {
            $lims_coupon_data = Coupon::find($data['coupon_id']);
            $lims_coupon_data->used += 1;
            $lims_coupon_data->save();
        }

        $lims_sale_data = Sale::create($data);
        $lims_customer_data = Customer::find($data['customer_id']);
        $lims_reward_point_setting_data = RewardPointSetting::latest()->first();
        //checking if customer gets some points or not
        if($lims_reward_point_setting_data->is_active &&  $data['grand_total'] >= $lims_reward_point_setting_data->minimum_amount) {
            $point = (int)($data['grand_total'] / $lims_reward_point_setting_data->per_point_amount);
            $lims_customer_data->points += $point;
            $lims_customer_data->save();
        }

        //collecting male data
        $mail_data['email'] = $lims_customer_data->email;
        $mail_data['reference_no'] = $lims_sale_data->reference_no;
        $mail_data['sale_status'] = $lims_sale_data->sale_status;
        $mail_data['payment_status'] = $lims_sale_data->payment_status;
        $mail_data['total_qty'] = $lims_sale_data->total_qty;
        $mail_data['total_price'] = $lims_sale_data->total_price;
        $mail_data['order_tax'] = $lims_sale_data->order_tax;
        $mail_data['order_tax_rate'] = $lims_sale_data->order_tax_rate;
        $mail_data['order_discount'] = $lims_sale_data->order_discount;
        $mail_data['shipping_cost'] = $lims_sale_data->shipping_cost;
        $mail_data['grand_total'] = $lims_sale_data->grand_total;
        $mail_data['paid_amount'] = $lims_sale_data->paid_amount;

        $product_id = $data['product_id'];
        $product_batch_id = $data['product_batch_id'];
        $imei_number = $data['imei_number'];
        $product_code = $data['product_code'];
        $qty = $data['qty'];
        $sale_unit = $data['sale_unit'];
        $net_unit_price = $data['net_unit_price'];
        $discount = $data['discount'];
        $tax_rate = $data['tax_rate'];
        $tax = $data['tax'];
        $total = $data['subtotal'];
        $product_sale = [];

        foreach ($product_id as $i => $id) {
            $lims_product_data = Product::where('id', $id)->first();
            $product_sale['variant_id'] = null;
            $product_sale['product_batch_id'] = null;
            if($lims_product_data->type == 'combo' && $data['sale_status'] == 1){
                $product_list = explode(",", $lims_product_data->product_list);
                $variant_list = explode(",", $lims_product_data->variant_list);
                if($lims_product_data->variant_list)
                    $variant_list = explode(",", $lims_product_data->variant_list);
                else
                    $variant_list = [];
                $qty_list = explode(",", $lims_product_data->qty_list);
                $price_list = explode(",", $lims_product_data->price_list);

                foreach ($product_list as $key=>$child_id) {
                    $child_data = Product::find($child_id);
                    if(count($variant_list) && $variant_list[$key]) {
                        $child_product_variant_data = ProductVariant::where([
                            ['product_id', $child_id],
                            ['variant_id', $variant_list[$key]]
                        ])->first();

                        $child_warehouse_data = Product_Warehouse::where([
                            ['product_id', $child_id],
                            ['variant_id', $variant_list[$key]],
                            ['warehouse_id', $data['warehouse_id'] ],
                        ])->first();

                        $child_product_variant_data->qty -= $qty[$i] * $qty_list[$key];
                        $child_product_variant_data->save();
                    }
                    else {
                        $child_warehouse_data = Product_Warehouse::where([
                            ['product_id', $child_id],
                            ['warehouse_id', $data['warehouse_id'] ],
                        ])->first();
                    }

                    $child_data->qty -= $qty[$i] * $qty_list[$key];
                    $child_warehouse_data->qty -= $qty[$i] * $qty_list[$key];

                    $child_data->save();
                    $child_warehouse_data->save();
                }
            }

            if($sale_unit[$i] != 'n/a') {
                $lims_sale_unit_data  = Unit::where('unit_name', $sale_unit[$i])->first();
                $sale_unit_id = $lims_sale_unit_data->id;
                if($lims_product_data->is_variant) {
                    $lims_product_variant_data = ProductVariant::select('id', 'variant_id', 'qty')->FindExactProductWithCode($id, $product_code[$i])->first();
                    $product_sale['variant_id'] = $lims_product_variant_data->variant_id;
                }
                if($lims_product_data->is_batch && $product_batch_id[$i]) {
                    $product_sale['product_batch_id'] = $product_batch_id[$i];
                }

                if($data['sale_status'] == 1) {
                    if($lims_sale_unit_data->operator == '*')
                        $quantity = $qty[$i] * $lims_sale_unit_data->operation_value;
                    elseif($lims_sale_unit_data->operator == '/')
                        $quantity = $qty[$i] / $lims_sale_unit_data->operation_value;
                    //deduct quantity
                    $lims_product_data->qty = $lims_product_data->qty - $quantity;
                    $lims_product_data->save();
                    //deduct product variant quantity if exist
                    if($lims_product_data->is_variant) {
                        $lims_product_variant_data->qty -= $quantity;
                        $lims_product_variant_data->save();
                        $lims_product_warehouse_data = Product_Warehouse::FindProductWithVariant($id, $lims_product_variant_data->variant_id, $data['warehouse_id'])->first();
                    }
                    elseif($product_batch_id[$i]) {
                        $lims_product_warehouse_data = Product_Warehouse::where([
                            ['product_batch_id', $product_batch_id[$i] ],
                            ['warehouse_id', $data['warehouse_id'] ]
                        ])->first();
                        $lims_product_batch_data = ProductBatch::find($product_batch_id[$i]);
                        //deduct product batch quantity
                        $lims_product_batch_data->qty -= $quantity;
                        $lims_product_batch_data->save();
                    }
                    else {
                        $lims_product_warehouse_data = Product_Warehouse::FindProductWithoutVariant($id, $data['warehouse_id'])->first();
                    }
                    //deduct quantity from warehouse
                    $lims_product_warehouse_data->qty -= $quantity;
                    $lims_product_warehouse_data->save();
                }
            }
            else
                $sale_unit_id = 0;

 $data['grand_total'];
        
      
    }
```

Comment: I don't think most of the code you provided is relevant to your specific question. It's far more likely for someone to go through your code and provide an answer if your code is more minimal and focuses only on your exact problem

Comment: @apokryfos now check

Comment: You seem to have a pivot model `Product_Sale`. That's not really recommended. If you want to use a `belongsToMany` in Laravel (e.g. a many to many relationship) you should let laravel manage the pivot table for you and then you can use things like `attach` to associate models